# gate: exporting gate to csv file with groovy

Tags: csv, groovy, gate

I hope somebody can help me and tell me what im doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Im excecuting this script on the groovy console in gate

```
new File("../outfile.csv").withWriterAppend{ out ->doc.getAnnotations().each {anno ->
  if( anno.getFeatures() )
    anno.getFeatures().each{ fName, fValue ->
      out.writeLine(/"${doc.getName()}","${anno.getType()}","${doc.stringFor(anno)}",${anno.start()},${anno.end()},"${fName}","${fValue}"/)
    }
  else
    out.writeLine(/"${doc.getName()}","${anno.getType()}","${doc.stringFor(anno)}",${anno.start()},${anno.end()},,/)        
}}
```

But im havig this exception

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: doc for class: ConsoleScript0

```
at ConsoleScript0$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript0:2)

at ConsoleScript0.run(ConsoleScript0:1)

at gate.groovy.GroovySupport$1$1$1.run(GroovySupport.java:134)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using the first example from the GATE [groovy recipes](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/groovy-recipes/).

The problem is that you're running your code in the groovy console. It should be run as part of a pipeline. Save your script in a groovy file and load it in a groovy PR.

According to [the docs](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html#x11-1800007.16.2) in the groovy PR you have variables inputAS, outputAS, doc, corpus, etc.

On the other hand, in the groovy console you have the "docs" variable so you can do something like:

```
docs.each{doc ->
  doc.getAnnotations().each ...
```